# Sum all integers in a PANDAS DataFrame "cell"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a PANDAS DF object where each "cell" is a list of tuples:

```
d = {"seen":[[('A', 4)], [], [('B', 4), ('C',3)], [('A', 1), ('C',4)]],\
 'unseen':[[('B', 2), ('C',2)], [('A', 4), ('B', 2), ('C',2)], [('A', 4)], 
[('C',1)]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

this is the result:

```
    seen                 unseen
0   [(A, 4)]            [(B, 2), (C, 2)]
1   []                  [(A, 4), (B, 2), (C, 2)]
2   [(B, 4), (C, 3)]    [(A, 4)]
3   [(A, 1), (C, 4)]    [(B, 1)]
```

I need to create a new DF with 4 columns: the length of each list-of-tuples + the sum of all the numbers in each cells:

```
    seen_count    seen_sum    unseen_count    unseen_sum
0   1             4           2               4  
1   0             0           3               8  
2   2             7           1               4  
3   2             5           1               1
```

I can iterate over the rows and count the length of each "cell" (list in this case), and then iterate over the tuples in each list and sum the numbers... but I'm hoping there's a more efficient method then this.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in creating the dataframe first when you're dealing with such a complicated set of rows. Clean it up first with custom functions before you make a dataframe out of it. The following is an illustration of clean up before dataframe creation:

```
import pandas as pd

# starting dictionary
d = {"seen":[[('A', 4)], [], [('B', 4), ('C',3)], [('A', 1), ('C',4)]],
     "unseen":[[('B', 2), ('C',2)], [('A', 4), ('B', 2), ('C',2)], [('A', 4)], [('C',1)]]
     }

# custom funcs
funcs = {'sum': lambda r: [sum(y[1] for y in x) for x in r],
         'count': lambda r: [len(y) for y in r]}

df = pd.DataFrame()
for k in d:
    for f in funcs:
        df["{k}_{f}".format(k=k, f=f)] = funcs.get(f)(d.get(k))

df

#    seen_count  seen_sum  unseen_count  unseen_sum
# 0           1         4             2           4
# 1           0         0             3           8
# 2           2         7             1           4
# 3           2         5             1           1
```

Comment: You're right, there is no point for making the first DF, but I need both.

Answer (score 5):

Let's use `df.agg`, lambda functions with a custom name, and `map` `join` to flatten multiindex column.

```
count_f = lambda x: x.str.len()
count_f.__name__ = '_count'
sum_f = lambda x: sum(i[1] for i in x)
sum_f.__name__ = '_sum'

df2 = df.agg([count_f, sum_f])
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(''.join)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   seen_count  seen_sum  unseen_count  unseen_sum
0           1         4             2           4
1           0         0             3           8
2           2         7             1           4
3           2         5             1           1
```

Comment: Good stuff, never used fn.__name__ before

Answer (score 2):

Using `applymap` you can

```
In [1346]: (df.applymap(lambda x: sum([t[1] for t in x]))
              .add_suffix('_sum')
              .join(df.applymap(len)
                      .add_suffix('_count')))
Out[1346]:
   seen_sum  unseen_sum  seen_count  unseen_count
0         4           4           1             2
1         0           8           0             3
2         7           4           2             1
3         5           1           2             1
```

Comment: I like to imagine this took you 1345 attempts to get just right ;)