# Adding values in a cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I am trying to add values in cells of one column in Pandas Dataframe. The dataframe was created:

```
data = [['ID_123456', 'example=1(abc)'], ['ID_123457', 'example=1(def)'], ['ID_123458', 'example=1(try)'], ['ID_123459', 'example=1(try)'], ['ID_123460', 'example=1(try),2(test)'], ['ID_123461', 'example=1(try),2(test),9(yum)'], ['ID_123462', 'example=1(try)'], ['ID_123463', 'example=1(try),7(test)']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'occ'])

display(df)
```

The table looks like this:

```
ID          occ
ID_123456   example=1(abc)
ID_123457   example=1(def)
ID_123458   example=1(try)
ID_123459   example=1(test)
ID_123460   example=1(try),2(test)
ID_123461   example=1(try),2(test),9(yum)
ID_123462   example=1(test)
ID_123463   example=1(try),7(test)
```

The following link is related to it but I was unable to run the command on my dataframe.

[Sum all integers in a PANDAS DataFrame "cell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016091/sum-all-integers-in-a-pandas-dataframe-cell)

The command gives an error of "string index out of range".

The output should look like this:

```
ID          occ                              count
ID_123456   example=1(abc)                     1
ID_123457   example=1(def)                     1
ID_123458   example=1(try)                     1
ID_123459   example=1(test)                    1
ID_123460   example=1(try),2(test)             3
ID_123461   example=1(try),2(test),9(yum)      12
ID_123462   example=1(test)                    1
ID_123463   example=1(try),7(test)             8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want sum all numbers on column `occ` use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), convert to integers with `sum`:

```
df['count'] = df['occ'].str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].astype(int).sum(level=0)
print (df)
          ID                            occ  count
0  ID_123456                 example=1(abc)      1
1  ID_123457                 example=1(def)      1
2  ID_123458                 example=1(try)      1
3  ID_123459                 example=1(try)      1
4  ID_123460         example=1(try),2(test)      3
5  ID_123461  example=1(try),2(test),9(yum)     12
6  ID_123462                 example=1(try)      1
7  ID_123463         example=1(try),7(test)      8
```